# Creating two nfs shares from same server, but when mounted, both point to same directory

Tags: ubuntu, nfs, mount

I've got a group of server that need two nfs shares, a few servers need access to one of the shares and all of the servers need access to another. The NFS server is ubuntu 12.04 and the others are 13.04
Here's my exports on the nfs server

```
    /u0/logshare/ 172.1.1.0/24(rw,fsid=0,insecure,no_subtree_check,async)
    /vmail1/ 172.1.1.64/27(rw,fsid=0,no_subtree_check,async,anonuid=2000,anongid=2000) 172.1.1.36(rw,fsid=0,no_subtree_check,async,anonuid=2000,anongid=2000)
```

Both of those are on separate partitions, logshare is ext4 and vmail is xfs, dunno if that could be relevant.

Here's what's in the fstab on the client server

```
    172.1.1.15:/vmail1           /vmail1         nfs     hard,intr,auto 0 0 
    172.1.1.15:/u0/logshare      /logshare     nfs     hard,intr,auto 0 0
```

but here's what I get after rebooting

```
172.1.1.15:/u0/logshare  4.1G  158M  3.8G   4% /logshare
172.1.1.15:/vmail1       4.1G  158M  3.8G   4% /vmail1
```

it's just mounted the logshare twice. If I reverse the order of the exports then it mounts the vmail twice. What's going on? I've been trhough the logs but don't see any errors relating to nfs

Showmount -e shows this
/vmail1      172.1.1.35,172.1.1.64/27
/u0/logshare 172.1.1.0/24

and the contents of both mounts are identical

Comment: What does showmount -e 172.1.1.15 from one of your servers give you?

Comment: Are the actual files duplicate at each mount point?

Comment: Showmount -e shows this  /vmail1      172.1.1.35,172.1.1.64/27
/u0/logshare 172.1.1.0/24 and the contents of both mounts are identical

Answer (score 4):

You should have started saying that this is an NFSv4 server.

The problem is in your `/etc/exports` file. You are declaring both resources with the `fsid=0` flag. That's wrong.

Read the [`exports(5)`](http://linux.die.net/man/5/exports) for the details, but basically:

```
For NFSv4, there is a distinguished filesystem which is the root of all exported filesystem. 
This is specified with fsid=root or fsid=0 both of which mean exactly the same thing.
```

I.e. you can only declare *one* root.

Common practice (although others might have different ones) is to create dedicated LVs (formatted as you need, `ext4`, `xfs`, ...) for the resources you plan to export, and `mount` them under a controlled directory structure. For example:

```
/var/exports/foo
/var/exports/bar
/var/exports/baz
```

Then, `mount` bind those resources under `/srv/nfsv4/`, resulting something in the lines of:

```
# tree /srv/nfsv4/
/srv/nfsv4/
├── bar
├── baz
└── foo
```

This way, you declare `/srv/nfsv4` your `fsid=0` and export the rest of the resources as you see fit.

Note that access restrictions (by IP, or `sec` mode chosen) in the `fsid=0` apply, so clients not satisfying the requirements in the `fsid=0` will fail to mount the resources, even if the requirements for an specific resource are fulfilled.